# Map objects properties and convert to string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

i ve this data :

```
let myInputArray = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "commercialRanges": [
          {
            "rangeId": "305",
            "rangeName": "FIXE"
          },
          {
            "rangeId": "306",
            "rangeName": "POSTPAID"
          },
        ],
        "active": true,
        "pefName": "Alertes",
        "roles": "ADVISOR",
        "equipmentTypes": "PC",
      },
      ...
      {
        "id": 1523,
        "commercialRanges": [
          {
            "rangeId": "700",
            "rangeName": "POSTPAID"
          },
          {
            "rangeId": "500",
            "rangeName": "PREPAID"
          },
        ]
        ,
        "active": true,
        "pefName": "Alertes",
        "roles": "ADVISOR",
        "equipmentTypes": "PC",
      },
    ]
```

I want to update my data:
Converting the attribute "commercialRanges" from its format (array of objects) 
-->   to a simple string: (which joining the different "**rangeName**" values )

**My resulting array would be something like this :**

```
myResultArray = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "commercialRanges": "FIXE,POSTPAID",
    "active": true,
    "pefName": "Alertes",
    "roles": "ADVISOR",
    "equipmentTypes": "PC",
  },
  ...
  {
    "id": 1523,
    "commercialRanges": "POSTPAID,PREPAID",
    "active": true,
    "pefName": "Alertes",
    "roles": "ADVISOR",
    "equipmentTypes": "PC",
  },
]
```

As a a result , i should convert the embedded object **"commercialRanges"**

```
"commercialRanges": [
      {
        "rangeId": "305",
        "rangeName": "FIXE"
      },
      {
        "rangeId": "306",
        "rangeName": "POSTPAID"
      },
    ]
```

**to** :

```
"commercialRanges": "FIXE,POSTPAID"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following using [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
let myInputArray = [{"id":1,"commercialRanges":[{"rangeId":"305","rangeName":"FIXE"},{"rangeId":"306","rangeName":"POSTPAID"}],"active":true,"pefName":"Alertes","roles":"ADVISOR","equipmentTypes":"PC"}];
  
myInputArray.forEach(o => o.commercialRanges = o.commercialRanges.map(r => r.rangeName).join(','));
console.log(myInputArray);
```

Comment: @firasKoubaa Keep in mind this approach mutates the `myInputArray`.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to loop through your `myInputArray` array and reduce `commercialRanges` to a string; for which you'll need to use a loop as well.

I'd suggest using `Array.prototype.reduce` method on your `myInputArray`, and then `Array.prototype.map` on `commercialRanges` Array, as that'd be the easiest/most elegant way of achieving this. You could also use `map` for both loops, as well as `reduce`. Up to you really. Here's my go

```
let myInputArray = [
  {
      "id": 1,
      "commercialRanges": [
        {
          "rangeId": "305",
          "rangeName": "FIXE"
        },
        {
          "rangeId": "306",
          "rangeName": "POSTPAID"
        },
      ],
      "active": true,
      "pefName": "Alertes",
      "roles": "ADVISOR",
      "equipmentTypes": "PC",
    },
    ...
    {
      "id": 1523,
      "commercialRanges": [
        {
          "rangeId": "700",
          "rangeName": "POSTPAID"
        },
        {
          "rangeId": "500",
          "rangeName": "PREPAID"
        },
      ]
      ,
      "active": true,
      "pefName": "Alertes",
      "roles": "ADVISOR",
      "equipmentTypes": "PC",
    },
  ]

const myInputString = myInputArray.reduce((arr, obj) => [
  ...arr,
  {
    ...obj,
    commercialRanges: obj.commercialRanges.map(rObj => rObj.rangeName).join(',')
  }
], [])
```

Option 2:
Looping both arrays with `Array.prototype.map`

```
const myInputString = myInputArray.map(obj => ({
    ...obj,
    commercialRanges: obj.commercialRanges.map(rObj => rObj.rangeName).join(',')
  })
)
```